# Can't get form to update mysql record

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a three part form that works like this, the first form is called create_ticket.php and it's basically a form with a customers contact info and what they want done. When the ticket is filled out it get's submitted to MySQL then when a search is done of the db you can select the ticket you want by clicking on the select link associated with that ticket in the search result and the browser will open a new window with the 2nd part of the form but it will pass the id associated with that MySQL record in the browser so you see at the end of the url ?id=10 now the 2nd part of the form is what a technician will use to fill out what they did and when they click get signature on the bottom of the page it will pop up the 3rd part of the form which allows the customer to sign on the tech's ipad or Toughbook and when they click accept it should update that record in MySQL associated with that id passed in the url. My issue is it's not working. so you can view the form at http://jemtechnv.com/test/ticket_results.php and see when you click on select it brings you to the technicians form to be filled out.
Here is my code that processes the 2nd part of the form:

```
<?php
// database connection //

include 'db/db_connect.php';

//This gets all the other information from the form

// start of form inputs //

$work_performed=$_POST['work_performed'];
$item_qty1=$_POST['item_qty1'];
$item_qty2=($_POST['item_qty2']);
$item_qty3=$_POST['item_qty1'];
$item_qty4=($_POST['item_qty2']);
$item_qty5=$_POST['item_qty1'];
$manuf_1=$_POST['manuf_1'];
$manuf_2=$_POST['manuf_2'];
$manuf_3=$_POST['manuf_3'];
$manuf_4=$_POST['manuf_4'];
$manuf_5=$_POST['manuf_5'];
$part_number1=$_POST['part_number1'];
$part_number2=$_POST['part_number2'];
$part_number3=$_POST['part_number3'];
$part_number4=$_POST['part_number4'];
$part_number5=$_POST['part_number5'];
$part_description1=$_POST['part_description1'];
$part_description2=$_POST['part_description2'];
$part_description3=$_POST['part_description3'];
$part_description4=$_POST['part_description4'];
$part_description5=$_POST['part_description5'];
$part1_price=$_POST['part_price1'];
$part2_price=$_POST['part_price2'];
$part3_price=$_POST['part_price3'];
$part4_price=$_POST['part_price4'];
$part5_price=$_POST['part_price5'];
$price_extension1=$_POST['price_extension1'];
$price_extension2=$_POST['price_extension2'];
$price_extension3=$_POST['price_extension3'];
$price_extension4=$_POST['price_extension4'];
$price_extension5=$_POST['price_extension5'];
$material_total=$_POST['material_total'];
$sales_tax=$_POST['sales_tax'];
$shipping_cost=$_POST['shipping_cost'];
$work_date1=$_POST['work_date1'];
$work_date2=$_POST['work_date2'];
$work_date3=$_POST['work_date3'];
$work_date4=$_POST['work_date4'];
$work_date5=$_POST['work_date5'];
$tech_name1=$_POST['tech_name1'];
$tech_name2=$_POST['tech_name2'];
$tech_name3=$_POST['tech_name3'];
$tech_name4=$_POST['tech_name4'];
$tech_name5=$_POST['tech_name5'];
$cost_code1=$_POST['cost_code1'];
$cost_code2=$_POST['cost_code2'];
$cost_code3=$_POST['cost_code3'];
$cost_code4=$_POST['cost_code4'];
$cost_code5=$_POST['cost_code5'];
$pay_rate1=$_POST['pay_rate1'];
$pay_rate2=$_POST['pay_rate2'];
$pay_rate3=$_POST['pay_rate3'];
$pay_rate4=$_POST['pay_rate4'];
$pay_rate5=$_POST['pay_rate5'];
$total_hours1=$_POST['total_hours1'];
$total_hours2=$_POST['total_hours2'];
$total_hours3=$_POST['total_hours3'];
$total_hours4=$_POST['total_hours4'];
$total_hours5=$_POST['total_hours5'];
$hours_subtotal1=$_POST['hours_subtotal1'];
$hours_subtotal2=$_POST['hours_subtotal2'];
$hours_subtotal3=$_POST['hours_subtotal3'];
$hours_subtotal4=$_POST['hours_subtotal4'];
$hours_subtotal5=$_POST['hours_subtotal5'];
$total_hours=$_POST['total_hours'];
$material_total=$_POST['material_total'];
$labor_cost=$_POST['labor_cost'];
$grand_total=$_POST['grand_total'];

//Writes the information to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE INTO tickets WHERE id=$id (work_performed, item_qty1, item_qty2, item_qty3, item_qty4, item_qty5,manuf_1, manuf_2, manuf_3, manuf_4, manuf_5, part_number1, part_number2, part_number3, part_number4, part_number5, part_description1, part_description2, part_description3, part_description_4, part_description_5, part1_price, part2_price, part3_price, part4_price, part5_price, price_extension1, price_extension2, price_extension3, price_extension4, price_extension5, material_total, sales_tax, shipping_cost, work_date1, work_date2, work_date3, work_date4, work_date5, tech_name1, tech_name2, tech_name3, tech_name4, tech_name5, cost_code1, cost_code2, cost_code3, cost_code4, cost_code5, pay_rate1, pay_rate2, pay_rate3, pay_rate4, pay_rate5, total_hours1, total_hours2, total_hours3, total_hours4, total_hours5, hours_subtotal1, hours_subtotal2, hours_subtotal3, hours_subtotal4, hours_subtotal5, total_hours, material_total, labor_cost, grand_total,)
VALUES ('$work_performed','$item_qty1','$item_qty2','$item_qty3','$item_qty4','$item_qty5','$mauf_1','$manuf_2','$manuf_3','$manuf_4','$manuf_5','$part_number1','$part_number2','$part_number3','$part_number4','$part_number5','$part_description1','$part_description2','$part_description3','$part_description_4',
'$part_description5','$part1_price','$part2_price','$part3_price','$part4_price','$part5_price','$price_extension1','$price_extension2','$price_extension3','$price_extension4','$price_extension5','$material_total','$sales_tax','$shipping_cost','$work_date1','$work_date2','$work_date3','$work_date4','$work_date5','$tech_name1','$tech_name2','$tech_name3','$tech_name4','$tech_name5','$cost_code1','$cost_code2','$cost_code3','$cost_code4','$cost_code5','$pay_rate1','$pay_rate2','$pay_rate3','$pay_rate4','$pay_rate5',
'$total_hours1','$total_hours2','$total_hours3','$total_hours4','$total_hours5','$hours_subtotal1','$hours_subtotal2','$hours_subtotal3','$hours_subtotal4','$hours_subtotal5','$total_hours','$material_total','$labor_cost','$grand_total',)") ; 



mysql_affected_rows();

    ?>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<br><br><br>
<form name="results" method="post" action="ticket_results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ticketresult">
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="ticketresult" style="width: 165px" value="Do Something">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm also aware I need to take MySQL injection precautions but honestly at the moment that's not a priority  as I just want to get the form working first then I will go back and clean up the code. Thanks for your help! I've disabled the signature portion of the form so clicking on get signature on the 2nd form will process the form and do the updates for that record, well it's supposed to but doesn't!

UPDATE: I have changed the query syntax as suggested below to this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tickets SET (work_performed, item_qty1, item_qty2, item_qty3, item_qty4, item_qty5,manuf_1, manuf_2, manuf_3, manuf_4, manuf_5, part_number1, part_number2, part_number3, part_number4, part_number5, part_description1, part_description2, part_description3, part_description_4, part_description_5, part1_price, part2_price, part3_price, part4_price, part5_price, price_extension1, price_extension2, price_extension3, price_extension4, price_extension5, material_total, sales_tax, shipping_cost, work_date1, work_date2, work_date3, work_date4, work_date5, tech_name1, tech_name2, tech_name3, tech_name4, tech_name5, cost_code1, cost_code2, cost_code3, cost_code4, cost_code5, pay_rate1, pay_rate2, pay_rate3, pay_rate4, pay_rate5, total_hours1, total_hours2, total_hours3, total_hours4, total_hours5, hours_subtotal1, hours_subtotal2, hours_subtotal3, hours_subtotal4, hours_subtotal5, total_hours, material_total, labor_cost, grand_total,)WHERE id=$id
VALUES ('$work_performed','$item_qty1','$item_qty2','$item_qty3','$item_qty4','$item_qty5','$mauf_1','$manuf_2','$manuf_3','$manuf_4','$manuf_5','$part_number1','$part_number2','$part_number3','$part_number4','$part_number5','$part_description1','$part_description2','$part_description3','$part_description_4',
'$part_description5','$part1_price','$part2_price','$part3_price','$part4_price','$part5_price','$price_extension1','$price_extension2','$price_extension3','$price_extension4','$price_extension5','$material_total','$sales_tax','$shipping_cost','$work_date1','$work_date2','$work_date3','$work_date4','$work_date5','$tech_name1','$tech_name2','$tech_name3','$tech_name4','$tech_name5','$cost_code1','$cost_code2','$cost_code3','$cost_code4','$cost_code5','$pay_rate1','$pay_rate2','$pay_rate3','$pay_rate4','$pay_rate5',
'$total_hours1','$total_hours2','$total_hours3','$total_hours4','$total_hours5','$hours_subtotal1','$hours_subtotal2','$hours_subtotal3','$hours_subtotal4','$hours_subtotal5','$total_hours','$material_total','$labor_cost','$grand_total',)");
```

but now I get the following error when I submit the form to update the database,

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(work_performed, item_qty1, item_qty2, item_qty3, item_qty4, item_qty5,manuf_1, ' at line 1

Comment: Right after include 'db/db_connect.php'; do a print_r($_POST); and post the output.

Comment: @IvoPereira I added the print_r($_POST) and when I submit the form it displays on the screen all the info being sent but nothing is posted in MySQL and I've made the changes suggested to my query as suggested below, my query is now UPDATE tickets SET etc etc etc WHERE id=$id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong. The query should be

```
UPDATE tickets  SET work_performed = something, item_qty1 = something .... WHERE id=$id
```

Comment: I'm not quit understanding what I need to do with the SET? do I have to add a statement after each of my variables or does it get that info from the form?

Comment: @JasonMcAdams You want to update the rows. And your update query is wrong. The correct syntax of using `UPDATE` is shown in my  answer.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar gave you the answer. Btw, to help you debugging in this case, do something like mysql_query('SELECT * FROM blabla') or die(mysql_error()); so you can get what's causing the error.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar so I changed my syntax to what you show and now I get this error and nothing is added to the database. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(work_performed, item_qty1, item_qty2, item_qty3, item_qty4, item_qty5,manuf_1, ' at line 1

Comment: @JasonMcAdams See my answer carefully. Your this update query is also wrong. It should be `UPDATE table_name  SET column_name = value1, column_name2 = value2,column_name3 = value3 .... WHERE id=$id`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar ok I think I understand, I made up a small test form and this is what I have for my update query,   mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name` SET 
                                  `city` = '$city',
                                 `state` = '$state',
                               `zip` = '$zip',
                               WHERE `id` = '$id'") 
Am I on the right track?